# When running WordPress Cron manually, it shows WP-Cron spawning is disabled. What is WP-Cron spawning?

Tags: wp-cron

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LEMP stack VPS. In this server, I run 13 WordPress sites. Every 10 minutes I have set up to run each site cron job with a 20 seconds interval. So every site does not execute cron jobs exact same time.

I edited crontab using the following command.

```
crontab -u www-data -e
```

When I go to the WordPress cron event plugin page, it shows `The DISABLE_WP_CRON constant is set to true. WP-Cron spawning is disabled.`

What is WP-Cron spawning? and can I enable it while using  `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

my crontab script sample.

```
while ! wget -q -O - https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do sleep 2 ; done ; echo ok
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is WP-Cron spawning?

First off, let's see what WP-Cron is and how it works:

- WP-Cron is how WordPress handles *scheduling time-based tasks* in WordPress, e.g. checking for core updates and publishing scheduled post.
- WP-Cron works by checking, on *every page load*, a list of scheduled tasks to see what needs to be run.
- Any tasks due to run will be called during that page load.

  And at this point, a cron spawning might happen, whereby WP-Cron would *send a request to run cron* through HTTP request that does not halt page loading. And note that the request is sent to `wp-cron.php`, e.g. `https://example.com/wp-cron.php`.

So WP-Cron spawning is basically **an automatic cron call that happens on page load**. See [`_wp_cron()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_cron/) and [`spawn_cron()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/spawn_cron/).

Therefore, if you manually run WordPress cron, then you should disable the automatic cron call since it will contribute to extra resource usage on your server. See [Hooking WP-Cron Into the System Task Scheduler](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/).

And thus, there should be no need to worry regarding the message that says WP-Cron spawning is disabled — it is probably merely a notice/reminder, or that the plugin might simply be trying to make a test cron request, but then did not proceed when it noticed WP-Cron spawning is disabled.

Nonetheless, if the spawning is disabled, then ensure that WordPress cron is still being executed properly, e.g. via the cron daemon in Linux and MacOS systems.

> can I enable it while using `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

WP-Cron spawning is *enabled by default*, but it can be disabled/enabled via the `DISABLE_WP_CRON` constant:

- **Disables** cron spawning — `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`
- **Enables** cron spawning — `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', false);`

However, if you have access to the system's task scheduler (to make a web request to the `wp-cron.php` file), then you should just disable WP-Cron spawning.

Comment: sally-cj thank you for your details reply. Yes, my WordPress cron jobs run without any issue.

Comment: Then, as I said in my answer, you can ignore the notice which says WP-Cron spawning is disabled.

Comment: But that notice is a plugin-specific notice, so if you want to know for sure why exactly the plugin displayed the notice, please ask on the plugin's support forums. As for your main question (what is WP-cron spawning), if my answer answered that question, I'd appreciate if you can mark my answer as correct.